# Reverse Array of coordinates in swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, reverse

I am trying to reverse an array of coordinates. I have this array:

```
[
            [
                9.211615025997162,
                44.30419567985762
            ],
            [
                9.21164184808731,
                44.30412081929745
            ],
            [
                9.21165257692337,
                44.304053636662175
            ],
            [
                9.211606979370117,
                44.3038789614507
            ],
            [
                9.211572110652924,
                44.30381945658962
            ],
            [
                9.211539924144745,
                44.30378874437967
            ],
            [
                9.211507737636566,
                44.30376187118276
            ],
            [
                9.211564064025879,
                44.30377530778277
            ],
            [
                9.211574792861937,
                44.30374075651943
            ],
            [
                9.211574792861937,
                44.30371388330059
            ],
            [
                9.211574792861937,
                44.30369852717
            ],
            [
                9.21154797077179,
                44.303665895379176
            ],
            [
                9.211513102054596,
                44.303650539236024
            ],
            [
                9.211429953575134,
                44.30358911462331
            ],
            [
                9.211349487304688,
                44.30355840229286
            ],
            [
                9.211271703243256,
                44.303537287556324
            ],
            [
                9.21117514371872,
                44.30349505806051
            ],
            [
                9.211151003837585,
                44.303473943301235
            ],
            [
                9.211126863956451,
                44.30342979423452
            ],
            [
                9.211145639419556,
                44.30339908182071
            ],
            [
                9.211183190345764,
                44.303368369390846
            ],
            [
                9.211223423480988,
                44.30331846165803
            ],
            [
                9.211242198944092,
                44.30327623200479
            ],
            [
                9.211177825927734,
                44.30325895622883
            ],
            [
                9.211030304431915,
                44.303228243725634
            ],
            [
                9.210925698280334,
                44.30321096793552
            ],
            [
                9.210874736309052,
                44.303197531206386
            ],
            [
                9.210831820964813,
                44.303197531206386
            ],
            [
                9.21075403690338,
                44.303197531206386
            ],
            [
                9.21068161725998,
                44.3031994507393
            ],
            [
                9.210577011108398,
                44.3031994507393
            ],
            [
                9.210509955883026,
                44.303207128870355
            ],
            [
                9.210440218448639,
                44.303207128870355
            ],
            [
                9.210370481014252,
                44.30322632419366
            ],
            [
                9.2102712392807,
                44.30324743904202
            ],
            [
                9.210190773010254,
                44.30328199059568
            ],
            [
                9.210112988948822,
                44.30328391012582
            ],
            [
                9.210059344768524,
                44.303297346835215
            ],
            [
                9.209954738616943,
                44.30332422024474
            ],
            [
                9.209901094436646,
                44.303339576473235
            ],
            [
                9.209868907928467,
                44.303349174114
            ],
            [
                9.209858179092407,
                44.30338372560779
            ],
            [
                9.209791123867035,
                44.30340292087333
            ],
            [
                9.209697246551514,
                44.30342595518367
            ],
            [
                9.209648966789246,
                44.3034509090097
            ],
            [
                9.209606051445007,
                44.30351809233474
            ],
            [
                9.209579229354858,
                44.30355840229286
            ],
            [
                9.209581911563873,
                44.3035852755829
            ],
            [
                9.209622144699097,
                44.30355840229286
            ],
            [
                9.20967847108841,
                44.30355648277167
            ],
            [
                9.209697246551514,
                    44.30354112659989
                ]
]
```

And I would like to reverse the coordinates, which are right now in Long-Lat to Lat-Long thus reversing the whole array or each item in the array would do the job here. I have been stuck trying to make it work, trying things like `arrayOfCoords.reversed()` and `.reverse()` to no avail. So how can I do this?

Comment: im a javascript guy, not swift. my thought would be run a loop in each item of array[i] and add the latter number to the beginning, then chop the last number. in js i would  array[i]unshift(array[i][1]); then array[i].pop; granted different language, but if you can find equivolents of these methods in swift, it should work and you wont have to store anything.

Comment: The best solution would be to use a struct for your coordinates, either a custom one or the built-in CLLocationCoordinate2D. That would make your code clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant/efficient way to do this, but I'd look at using `compactMap`:

```
let testArray = [[1.123,2.22], [3.11, 4.0], [5.21, 6.19]]
print(testArray)
```

> [[1.123, 2.22], [3.11, 4.0], [5.21, 6.19]]

```
let flippedElementArray = testArray.compactMap { $0.count > 1 ? [$0[1], $0[0]] : nil }
print(flippedElementArray)
```

> [[2.22, 1.123], [4.0, 3.11], [6.19, 5.21]]

The `$0.count > 1` check just makes sure you have at least 2 elements so you don't get a bounds error. If not, the closure returns nil for that element, which will be filtered out by `compactMap`. Otherwise, it returns a new array element consisting of the second element followed by the first element. All of those elements are stored in the final mapped array (`flippedElementArray`).

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayOfCoords.map{ Array($0.reversed()) }
```

I'm assuming you want to reverse each coordinate pair, but keep the pairs themselves in the original order. Since you have an array of arrays, you have to do the operation on each sub-array separately. And `reversed()` returns a ReversedCollection instead of an Array so you have to re-initialize it into an array to use it properly.

Comment: This looks like it should do the same thing as my solution with less code, but i noticed that it prints as:
[Swift.ReversedCollection<Swift.Array<Swift.Double>>(_base: [1.123, 2.22]), Swift.ReversedCollection<Swift.Array<Swift.Double>>(_base: [3.11, 4.0]), Swift.ReversedCollection<Swift.Array<Swift.Double>>(_base: [1.22, 32.2]), Swift.ReversedCollection<Swift.Array<Swift.Double>>(_base: [5.21, 6.19])]


Any idea how to clean that up to just be a normal array of arrays? I guess the element arrays are not actually reversed, just flagged to be treated as reversed when accessed.